# Proving a homeomorphism when graph of function has product topology

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $f : (X,d_x) \rightarrow (Y,d_y)$ is a function between metric spaces, and $X \times Y$ has the product topology.

The graph $G_f$ is the subspace $G_f = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X\}$.

Define $\rho: X \rightarrow \gamma_f$ by $\rho (x) = (x, f(x))$ 
How do I show that $\rho$ is a homeomorphism? Should I use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity or preimages? Also, why is the inverse of $\rho$ continuous?

Comment: What is $\gamma_f$, do you mean $G_f$ ?

Comment: Your frequent alternation into and out of MathJax within a single expression is not proper MathJax usage. See my edits.  The expression "$G_f = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X\}$" is now in just one set of MathJax tags.  Strangely, there was one place where you should have excluded something from MathJax but didn't: I changed $\varepsilon-\delta$ (which in effect had a minus sign instead of a hyphen) to $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ (with an actual hyphen where a hyphen belongs). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, I do mean $G_f$, sorry. Also, thanks for cleaning up my code - still quite the newbie to LaTeX over here so I appreciate the pointers a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the definition of continuity with which you are most comfortable.  I will unpack both definitions, which should be a starting point for the proof.  On the space $X\times Y$, I will use the notation $d_{XY}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \max\{d_X(x_1,x_2), d_Y(y_1, y_2)\}$ for the metric on the product $X \times Y$.

For $\rho$ to be continuous means either:

- For open sets $U\subset X, V \subset Y$, then  the preimage $\rho^{-1}(G_f \cap (U  \times V))$ is open in $X$.
  or
- For all $x\in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_{XY}((x,f(x)), (x',f(x')) = \max\{d_X(x,x'),d_Y(f(x), f(x'))\} < \epsilon$ for all $x'$ such that $d_X(x,x')< \delta$.

I will note that for $\rho$ to be continuous, you will need $f$ to be continuous (which might be implicit in your definition of a map of metric spaces), so you're going to need to use that fact in your proof.

For $\rho^{-1}$ to be continuous means either:

- For all open sets $U\subset X$, the image $\rho(U)$ is open in $G_f$.

or

- For all $x\in X$ and $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_X(x,x')< \epsilon$ for all $x'\in X$ such that $d_{XY}((x,f(x)), (x',f(x')) = \max\{d_X(x,x'),d_Y(f(x), f(x'))\} < \delta$.

Hopefully this helps.